# Duplicated frames when mering multiple videos with xfade filter (ffmpeg)

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

I'm stuck with merging multiple videos with audio. This used to work on most videos I merged before but with some videos, I get the "More than 1000 frames duplicated" warning, and the output video is broken (some videos won't play, just static picture and the sound is misaligned).

All videos are in the same format afaik. The only difference I see is that some are "yuvj420p(pc)" and most are "yuv420p". But I tried merging without those with "yuvj420p(pc)" and it didn't help.

Already tried adding "-vsync vfr", didn't help too.
Interestingly — if I remove the second or the last input video, no warning is given and it all works.

The command I use:

```
ffmpeg  -i intro.mp4 \
     -i 2043651222.mp4 \
     -i 2668231460.mp4 \
     -i 2342967217.mp4 \
     -i 2345792509.mp4 \
     -i 2764881879.mp4 \
     -i 3127825310.mp4 \
     -i 3058954129.mp4 \
     -i 2533841315.mp4 \
     -i 2334544474.mp4 \
     -i 2493440007.mp4 \
     -filter_complex \
"[0][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=3.5000000[V01]; \
[V01][2]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=7.67000[V02]; \
[V02][3]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=27.21000[V03]; \
[V03][4]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=37.01000[V04]; \
[V04][5]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=54.11000[V05]; \
[V05][6]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=56.63000[V06]; \
[V06][7]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=80.49000[V07]; \
[V07][8]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=107.23000[V08]; \
[V08][9]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=110.12000[V09]; \
[V09][10]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=118.31000,format=yuv420p[video]; \
[0:a]aresample=async=1:first_pts=0,apad,atrim=0:4[A0]; \
[1:a]aresample=async=1:first_pts=0,apad,atrim=0:4.67[A1]; \
[2:a]aresample=async=1:first_pts=0,apad,atrim=0:20.04[A2]; \
[3:a]aresample=async=1:first_pts=0,apad,atrim=0:10.3[A3]; \
[4:a]aresample=async=1:first_pts=0,apad,atrim=0:17.6[A4]; \
[5:a]aresample=async=1:first_pts=0,apad,atrim=0:3.02[A5]; \
[6:a]aresample=async=1:first_pts=0,apad,atrim=0:24.36[A6]; \
[7:a]aresample=async=1:first_pts=0,apad,atrim=0:27.24[A7]; \
[8:a]aresample=async=1:first_pts=0,apad,atrim=0:3.39[A8]; \
[9:a]aresample=async=1:first_pts=0,apad,atrim=0:8.69[A9]; \
[10:a]aresample=async=1:first_pts=0,apad,atrim=0:14.88[A10]; \
[A0][A1]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A0001]; \
[A0001][A2]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A0002]; \
[A0002][A3]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A0003]; \
[A0003][A4]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A0004]; \
[A0004][A5]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A0005]; \
[A0005][A6]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A0006]; \
[A0006][A7]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A0007]; \
[A0007][A8]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A0008]; \
[A0008][A9]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A0009]; \
[A0009][A10]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[audio] \
" -map "[video]" -map "[audio]" -movflags +faststart 'compiled.mp4'
```

Full log:

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'intro.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:04.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 98 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 2 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 85 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2043651222.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:04.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 471 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 333 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2668231460.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:20.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1882 kb/s
    Stream #2:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280, 1685 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Stream #2:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 191 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2342967217.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:10.30, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 446 kb/s
    Stream #3:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 367 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #3:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #4, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2345792509.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:17.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2546 kb/s
    Stream #4:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280, 2342 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Stream #4:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 199 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
Input #5, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2764881879.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:03.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1293 kb/s
    Stream #5:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280, 1110 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Stream #5:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 178 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
Input #6, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '3127825310.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:24.36, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 401 kb/s
    Stream #6:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 323 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #6:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #7, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '3058954129.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:27.24, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1723 kb/s
    Stream #7:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280, 1519 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Stream #7:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 194 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
Input #8, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2533841315.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:03.39, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1807 kb/s
    Stream #8:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280, 1657 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Stream #8:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 150 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
Input #9, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2334544474.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:08.69, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2675 kb/s
    Stream #9:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280, 2500 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Stream #9:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 180 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
Input #10, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2493440007.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:14.88, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 966 kb/s
    Stream #10:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280, 889 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Stream #10:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
File 'compiled.mp4' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (aac) -> aresample
  Stream #0:1 (h264) -> xfade:main
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #1:1 (aac) -> aresample
  Stream #2:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #2:1 (aac) -> aresample
  Stream #3:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #3:1 (aac) -> aresample
  Stream #4:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #4:1 (aac) -> aresample
  Stream #5:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #5:1 (aac) -> aresample
  Stream #6:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #6:1 (aac) -> aresample
  Stream #7:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #7:1 (aac) -> aresample
  Stream #8:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #8:1 (aac) -> aresample
  Stream #9:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #9:1 (aac) -> aresample
  Stream #10:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #10:1 (aac) -> aresample
  format -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  acrossfade -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x7ff21ef72000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0x7ff227827800] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7ff227827800] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7ff227827800] profile High, level 3.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x7ff227827800] 264 - core 160 r3011M cde9a93 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'compiled.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 aac
More than 1000 frames duplicated    1024kB time=00:00:47.41 bitrate= 176.9kbits/s dup=597 drop=996 speed=5.81x    
[mp4 @ 0x7ff227815200] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the filep=1954 speed=4.07x    
frame= 3989 fps=121 q=-1.0 Lsize=   13252kB time=00:02:12.98 bitrate= 816.3kbits/s dup=1946 drop=1954 speed=4.05x    
video:11094kB audio:2036kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.927680%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff227827800] frame I:23    Avg QP:14.09  size: 69236
[libx264 @ 0x7ff227827800] frame P:1195  Avg QP:18.60  size:  6527
[libx264 @ 0x7ff227827800] frame B:2771  Avg QP:21.69  size:   710
[libx264 @ 0x7ff227827800] consecutive B-frames:  3.3% 11.5%  2.6% 82.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff227827800] mb I  I16..4: 36.4% 41.9% 21.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff227827800] mb P  I16..4:  3.1%  6.0%  1.1%  P16..4: 15.4%  5.5%  2.9%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:66.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff227827800] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8: 10.2%  0.6%  0.0%  direct: 0.4%  skip:88.5%  L0:42.8% L1:53.3% BI: 3.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff227827800] 8x8 transform intra:55.8% inter:63.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff227827800] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 25.6% 42.8% 14.5% inter: 2.7% 2.5% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff227827800] i16 v,h,dc,p: 45% 22% 14% 19%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff227827800] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 38% 19% 28%  3%  2%  3%  2%  3%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff227827800] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 32% 17% 15%  6%  7%  8%  5%  6%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff227827800] i8c dc,h,v,p: 55% 15% 23%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff227827800] Weighted P-Frames: Y:2.0% UV:1.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff227827800] ref P L0: 68.4% 13.3% 14.4%  3.9%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff227827800] ref B L0: 86.0% 12.0%  2.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff227827800] ref B L1: 96.9%  3.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff227827800] kb/s:683.43
[aac @ 0x7ff22781fc00] Qavg: 2168.180
```

Comment: Recommend providing a minimal command that still shows the issue.

Comment: @llogan I wish I could. That's the problem.. if I remove one input video, one crossfade and trimming things get normal and the video assembles well. With one less video the "More than 1000 frames duplicated" goes away.

Comment: Can you provide a link to all 11 input files?

Comment: Just tried to run xfade and triimng+crossfade apart, on 28 input videos. And it works. Output files are almost the same duration. Does this help anyhow?

ffprobe of two output files: https://pastebin.com/QCj7sQJq

Comment: Another update — I just merged the complied video with audio and everything is perfectly in sync. Why this does not work in one go remains a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know why this is happening. I also got the same error when trying to merge 11 files using the xfade filter.
I used ffprobe to get the length of the video like this:

```
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format compact=print_section=0:nokey=1:escape=csv -show_entries format=duration video.MP4
```

and got: 9.003000. So I set offset=8.003.

In fact, the duration of the video stream should be defined as follows:

```
ffprobe -v quiet -select_streams v:0 -print_format compact=print_section=0:nokey=1:escape=csv -show_entries stream=duration video.MP4
```

then got: 8.000000. And I had to set offset=7.

Because audio and video durations often differ:

```
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format compact=print_section=0:nokey=1:escape=csv -show_entries stream=duration video.MP4
```

gave this: 8.000000 9.002667

If the duration differs by more than one second, then the process is interrupted (for duration =1) due to the fact that offset exceeds the duration of the video stream.